# Dependency between two Eclipse projects: how to add one's classpath into second's?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies, classpath

I'm working on two projects `A` and `B`:

- `A` is a Maven project that has Guava as dependency, and is packaged into a JAR;
- `B` is a *classic* web project (i.e. without Maven), is packaged into a WAR, and uses `A`'s JAR.

`A` and `B` both are Eclipse projects. To make `B` able to use `A`'s classes without having to re-package `A` each time, I right-clicked on `B` in Eclipse > Properties > Deployment Assembly > Add > Project > `A`.

`B` thus compiles, but on runtime, when I call a class of `A` that uses Guava, I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` caused by a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`, since `B` doesn't have Guava into its classpath (even though he has `A`).

Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: The Guava-library is contained in the deployment assembly?

Comment: @frostjogla Thanks, that was it! When I add Guava in the Deployment Assembly of `A`, I can get it from `B`. Interesting, I think I didn't get it all ;) Don't hesitate to add a *real* answer to my post, I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add guava-library in the deployment assembly. =)